# Azure B2C. User account does not exist in tenant 'xxx' and cannot access application

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We get the following error when trying to access an AAD application, which is connected to Azure B2C.

> User account 'xxxxx@gmail.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'xxxxxxxx' and cannot access the application 'xxxxxxxxxxx' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

The live account shows up in both the B2C and AAD as a live.com user.  Manually created accounts can log in.  Yet when logging in from a B2C account, I get the above error.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirement is to accept both personal accounts in addition to corporate accounts, then you should not be using ADAL. ADAL/ADAL.JS is designed only to accept corporate accounts and use the so called Azure AD 'v1' endpoint.

Here are your options:

1. AppSource only requires corporate accounts sign-ins. If you only need AppSource certification, you can keep using adal.js to sign-in corporate accounts. Then what you need to do is to set your application to be multi-tenant in Azure Portal, so you don't need to add guest accounts. But, again, this option only accepts corporate account sign-ins.
2. If your requirement is to also accept personal accounts, then you need to use msal.js instead of adal.js - and then register your application in the new portal https://apps.dev.microsoft.com . This new application is known as converged application and uses the Azure AD v2 endpoint. To get started use [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-javascriptspa) as a starting point to sign-in users using msal.js.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful for a starting point.  Option 2 seems like exactly what we needed to solve this problem.