# Add users to Azure AD Enterprise Application

Tags: php, azure, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I'm integrating the Microsoft SSO in my app using the SAML 2 protocol. I managed to create a new Enterprise App in the Azure portal and successfully added the SSO with the help of the SimpeSAMLphp library. Now when I login with an account that is not the Azure AD I get a specific error message

```
AADSTS50020: User account ... from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in 
tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application ... in that tenant. The 
account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in
 again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.
```

I know that in order for users to be able to use the Microsoft SSO they need to be added as a User/Group in Azure AD, but I would like to send the user an invitation (using the Microsoft Graph API) if they are not added in Azure AD and if they are in the Database. The problem is that I couldn't find any way to catch this error or any other workaround. I also tried getting the user's email after they add they try to sign in with their mail on Microsoft. Is there any way this is possible? (I also need my app to use the SAML protocol so I can't create a usual Application int Azure AD and use oAuth).

Comment: You can refer to [Setup Single Sign On with AAD using SimpleSAMLphp](https://azureossd.github.io/2016/08/15/setup-single-sign-on-with-aad-using-simplesamlphp/), [Assign users and groups to an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal) and [Error AADSTS50020 - User account from identity provider does not exist in tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT thank you for your answer. I already did all those steps in the configuration process that are presented in the pages that you provided me with, but the thing that I would like to know if it is possible to get at least the user's email when they are given that error message so I can send them an invite if their account was already created.

Comment: Any update on this.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround may help:

> I would like to know if it is possible to get at least the user's
> email when they are given that error message so I can send them an
> invite if their account was already created.

To achieve the above requirement you may need to use V2 endpoints to allow access from personal Microsoft accounts.

e.g:- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` and redirect uri as `http://jwt.ms`.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=ffffff-1111-2222-3333-xxx
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=http://jwt.ms
&response_mode=form_post
&prompt=consent
&scope=openid
&state=12345
&nonce=RandomGUI
```

P.S:- *Please provide the client Id, Tenant ID of your application.*

By doing so you can get the sign in failed user emails and can can send the invite to that  user.

In alternative solution :- *Your application can use [***Azure AD B2C***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) to authenticate with any Microsoft account. Microsoft Account can be added as a social identity provider. So that anyone with a live account may sign in/up to your app using Azure AD B2C.*

For more information please refer the below links:

- ***SO THREAD***|[***AADSTS50020 error when authenticating user with live.com based account***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728455/aadsts50020-error-when-authenticating-user-with-live-com-based-account?rq=1)

[***User account does not exist in tenant 'xxx' and cannot access application***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341723/azure-b2c-user-account-does-not-exist-in-tenant-xxx-and-cannot-access-applica?rq=1) &

[***Azure AD authentication failing when using ms live accounts other than my AAD account***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587560/azure-ad-authentication-failing-when-using-ms-live-accounts-other-than-my-aad-ac?rq=1).